# ReactJS/NodeJS CORS request did not succeed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, apache, axios

I use Axios to sending request to my NodeJS server. This is my request:

```
let url = 'http://example.com:1337/api/'

let config = {
    headers: { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}

settings = (data) => {
    return axios.post(url + 'settings', JSON.stringify(data), config)
    .then( res => res.data)
    .catch(e => console.log(e))
}
```

In NodeJS/ExpressJS server:

```
const express = require('express')
const App = express()
let bodyParser = require('body-parser')
// ... Mongoose and etc.

var cors = require('cors')


App.use(cors())
App.options('*', cors());

App.use("/data", express.static(__dirname + '/data'));

App.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
App.use(bodyParser.json())

App.use('/api', require('./routes/Users'))

App.listen(1337)
```

But request to `http://example.com:1337/api/settings` returns (firefox):

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://example.com:1337/api/settings. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)
```

Thank you for your solutions.

Comment: Make your example more clear for more quality answers. Your backend example gives us no any data that we could work with. We have no idea what your vars `App` and `cors` are even tho someone might try guessing.

Comment: @JimiPajala I added more information. Thanks.

Comment: Why ```http://example.com```? Are you correctly resolving it?

Answer (score 0):

```
// server.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const routes = require('./routes');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

// configure body parser for AJAX requests
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

app.use(routes);

//Server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

Comment: `App.use(cors())
App.options('*', cors())`

not Worked

Comment: I have updated my answer which I used and its work perfect for me. https://github.com/asifvora/mern-stack-app

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const express = require('express')
const App = express()
let bodyParser = require('body-parser')
// ... Mongoose and etc.
  App.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
          res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
          res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type");
          res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST","PUT");
          next();
        });

App.use("/data", express.static(__dirname + '/data'));

App.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
App.use(bodyParser.json())

App.use('/api', require('./routes/Users'))

App.listen(1337)
```